# Regular expression in ruby and matching so many results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Trying to create a simple regular expression that can extract numbers(between 7 - 14) after a keyword starting with g letter and some id, something like following :

```
(g)(\d{1,6})\s+(\d{7,14}\s*)+
```

Lets assume :

```
m = (/(g)(\d{1,6})\s+(\d{7,14}\s*)+/i.match("g12 327638474 83873478 2387327683 44 437643673476"))
```

I have results of :

```
#<MatchData "g23333 327638474 83873478 2387327683 " "g" "12" "2387327683 ">
```

But what I need as a final result , to include, 327638474, 83873478, 2387327683 and exclude 44.

For now I just getting the last number 2387327683 with not including the previous numbers

Any help here .

cheers

Comment: What makes you think that regular expressions are a good tool to do this? The description is not entirely clear to me. Can you give more examples of what would be valid input, along with the desired output?

Comment: sure, if u have any idea pleas share it, as for me i need some valid input with form of : G{ID} Num1 Num2 ...  Numbers supposed to be between 7-14, the desired output Num1 Num2 ....

Comment: Do you need to extract those kinds of string from a bigger string or do you just need to extract the information from a string that already starts with a `g`?

Comment: yup I want to extract the information from the string contain g .

Comment: the weird thing i'm facing , the current regex just include 2387327683 , which is the last valid number, with no other numbers as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a FYI, here is a benchmark showing a bit faster way of accomplishing the selected answer:

```
require 'ap'
require 'benchmark'

n = 100_000

s = "g12 327638474 83873478 2387327683 44 437643673476"

ap s.split[1..-1].select { |x| (7..14).include? x.size }.map(&:to_i)
ap s.split[1..-1].select { |x| 7 <= x.size && x.size <= 14 }.map(&:to_i)

Benchmark.bm(11) do |b|
  b.report('include?'   ) { n.times{ s.split[1..-1].select { |x| (7..14).include? x.size }.map(&:to_i)     } }
  b.report('conditional') { n.times{ s.split[1..-1].select { |x| 7 <= x.size && x.size <= 14 }.map(&:to_i) } }
end

ruby ~/Desktop/test.rb 
[
    [0] 327638474,
    [1] 83873478,
    [2] 2387327683,
    [3] 437643673476
]
[
    [0] 327638474,
    [1] 83873478,
    [2] 2387327683,
    [3] 437643673476
]
                 user     system      total        real
include?     1.010000   0.000000   1.010000 (  1.011725)
conditional  0.830000   0.000000   0.830000 (  0.825746)
```

For speed I'll use the conditional test. It's a tiny bit more verbose, but is still easily read.

Comment: That's one aspect where Python is ahead of Ruby: `7 <= len(x) <= 14`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a regex, you can use something like that:

```
s = "g12 327638474 83873478 2387327683 44 437643673476"
s.split[1..-1].select { |x| (7..14).include?(x.size) }.map(&:to_i)
# => [327638474, 83873478, 2387327683, 437643673476]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help here, anyways let's say s = "G23333 11111111 2222222 3333333 44 555555555", i will get results with no 555555555 , as you can see I wanna include all numbers between 7-14

Comment: @Eqbal: Oh sorry, must have misinterpreted your question. This isn't doable with pure regex, so I deleted the regex solution and updated the more general (and better) pure-Ruby solution.